# how to get the hidden value from the same page

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

My script

```
function fnsort(firstname)
    {
                alert("hi")
                alert(  $('#hidetxt').val().length);
                if($('#hidetxt').val().length ==0 )
                {
                    $("#hidetxt").val("firstname Asc");
                   // alert(    $('#hidetxt').val());
                   loadval();
                   alert("asc function")

                }
                else
                {
                    var str="firstname Asc";
                    var n=str.split(" ");
                    if(n[0] == "firstname")
                    {
                        $("#hidetxt").val("firstname Desc");
                        alert("desc function")
                        $('#hidetxt').val("")
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Control is wrong")
                    }
                }
            /*document.getElementById('form2').action="display_report.cfm"; 
                document.getElementById('form2').submit();  */
    }
    function loadval()
    {
        <cfoutput>
            <cfquery name="result" datasource="Training">
                select TE.firstname,TE.lastname,TD.deparmentname,TE.salary,TE.DateOfBirth
                from TEmployee as TE 
                inner join Tdepartment as TD
                on TE.departmentID=TD.departmentID
                where 1 = 1
                <cfif len(form.fname) gt 0 >
                AND TE.FirstName Like  '#Form.fname#%'
                </cfif>
                <cfif len(form.lname) gt 0>
                and TE.LastName Like '#Form.lname#%'
                </cfif>
                <cfif  form.dept neq 0>
                and TD.DeparmentName='#form.dept#'
                order by "#form.hidetxt#"
                </cfif>
                <cfif ListLen(Form.salary,'-') EQ 2>
                AND TE.salary between #ListGetAt(Form.salary,1,'-')# AND #ListGetAt(Form.salary,2,'-')#
                order by "#form.hidetxt#"
                </cfif>
            </cfquery>
        <!--- <cfquery name="result" datasource="Training">
            select TE.firstname,TE.lastname,TD.deparmentname,TE.salary,TE.DateOfBirth
             from TEmployee as TE,Tdepartment as TD
                where TE.departmentID=TD.departmentID
                    <cfif #len(form.fname)# gt 0 and #len(form.lname)# gt 0>
                          and TE.firstname=<cfqueryparam value="#Form.fname#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR"> and TE.lastname=<cfqueryparam value="#Form.lname#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR"> 
                    </cfif>
         </cfquery> --->
        </cfoutput>
    }
</script>
```

my html

```
<body  onload="loadval()" >
        <form method="post" id="form2">
        <input type="hidden" name="hidetxt" value="" id="hidetxt">

            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td onclick="fnsort('firstname')">
                        <b>Firstname</b>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <b>Lastname</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b> Departname</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b> Salary</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b> Dob</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <cfoutput query="result">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>#result.firstname# </b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>#result.lastname#</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <b>#result.deparmentname# </b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>#result.salary# </b>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <b>#result.DateOfBirth#</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </cfoutput> 
            </table>

                <!--- <input type="text" name="txtfname" id="txtfname"> --->
        </form>
    </body>
```

Error : Element HIDETXT is undefined in FORM. Please tell me how to rectify this

I need to sort the firstname when i click the cell the firstname . i got this error how to get the "form.hidetxt" value . This page name is "display_report.cfm"

Comment: having your <cfquery> inside your javascript makes no sense.   You're confusing your server-side and client-side languages.

Comment: You should understand difference between client side and server side script. If you are thinking ColdFusion code will execute when you call javascript function will never work.

Comment: @Bhargavi - As others have said, just wrapping a cfquery in javascript does not make it magically execute when that javascript function is invoked. CF code only executes on the CF Server. It executes *first*, long before any javascript code runs. If you wish to execute additional CF code, *after* the page is already rendered to the client, you must submit a *new* HTTP request. I suggest reading up on [the CFML request/response process](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html) to better understand why the code isn't going to work the way you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The Value of #HIDETXT is empty because

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidetxt" *value=""* id="hidetxt">
```

it is default empty and

```
loadval()
```

will not set this value.. furthermore

```
function fnsort(firstname)
{
            alert("hi")
            alert(  $('#hidetxt').val().length); // #hidetxt is nul
            if($('#hidetxt').val().length ==0 )
            {
                $("#hidetxt").val("firstname Asc"); // here #hidetxt have to be "firstname Asc"
               // alert(    $('#hidetxt').val()); 
               loadval();
               alert("asc function")

            }
            else
            {
                var str="firstname Asc";
                var n=str.split(" ");
                if(n[0] == "firstname")
                {
                    $("#hidetxt").val("firstname Desc"); // here #hidetxt has to be "firstname Desc"
                    alert("desc function") // fix ;
                    $('#hidetxt').val("") // fix ; and #hidetxt will be ""
                }   
                else
                {
                    alert("Control is wrong")
                }
            }
        /*document.getElementById('form2').action="display_report.cfm"; 
            document.getElementById('form2').submit();  */
}
```

i think you have to

```
console.log($('#hidetxt')
```

to test if the element is found yet..

after this try to init it with values by running your methods..

Comment: ya i got the value . but value is not passing in query

Comment: you mean that the value is not in the submit query?